# Command not found when running a script- variable does not seem to register

Tags: bash, scripting, command

I am trying to create a simple script whereby I compare a user input (bday) and compare it with the current date in a certain format.

The result I get is that [$bday..] command not found?

Would appreciate the help on this, with an explanation

````bash
#!/bin/bash

echo please enter your bday YYYY-MM-DD
read bday
dates=$(date +%F)
echo $dates

if [$bday == $dates]
then
 echo Happy Birthday
else
 echo Happy not Birthday
fi

#strip $date of day-month-year integers only
#arrange into YYY-MM-DD
#compare the two
#date --help```
````

Comment: whitespace is significant. `[a = b]` != `[ a = b ]`. Also, `a = b` != `a=b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line here is missing whitespace.

`if [$bday == $dates]`

Here the shell is searching for a command named `[$bday` which doesn't exist and throws an error. It should instead be

`if [ $bday == $dates ]`